# Using a function to calculate the frequency of columns in a dataframe (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the following data set:

```
Index    ADR   EF   INF   SS
1         1     1    0     0
2         1     0    1     1
3         0     1    0     0
4         0     0    1     1
5         1     0    1     1
```

I am going to calculate the frequency for each column. This is my code:

```
df.ADR.value_counts()
df.EF.value_counts()
df.INF.value_counts()
df.SS.value_counts()
```

How I can do it by writing a function, rather than repeating the code for each column? I tried this:

```
def frequency (df, *arg): 
    count =df.arg.value_counts()
    return (count)
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to calculate the frequency of all columns, rather than selectively, I don't recommend a custom function.

Try using `df.apply`, passing `pd.value_counts`:

```
In [1048]: df.apply(pd.value_counts, axis=0)
Out[1048]: 
   ADR  EF  INF  SS
0    2   3    2   2
1    3   2    3   3
```

If you want to calculate selectively, you may pass a list of columns to a function:

```
def foo(df, columns):
    return df[columns].apply(pd.value_counts, axis=0)

print(foo(df, ['ADR', 'EF']))
```

Comment: Yes, I want to pass it selectively. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Mary This will work if you pass any number or order of columns, but pass it as a list. Glad I could help.

Comment: Nice `apply`!! ~~

Comment: @COLDSPEED, yes I got it. I have another question. If I want to group by them with another column, then how the function should be ?

Comment: @Wen Oh hey there buddy.

Comment: @Mary Can't say for certain unless I know what your expected output looks like :) Maybe open another question? I'd be happy to help. Don't want to give you misinformation and cause problems.

Comment: OK, sure. I do it now

Comment: Let us wait for the new question ~:)

Comment: @Mary Don't forget, you can accept this answer if it helped. Let me know when you've opened a new question.

Comment: Thank you. I did :)

Comment: @ COLDSPEED, this is the link for my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45359128/using-a-function-to-calculate-the-frequency-of-columns-using-groupby-in-a-datafr

Answer (score 3):

If you only have value 0 and 1

```
Freq=pd.concat([(df==0).sum(),(df==1).sum()],axis=1)
Out[62]: 
       0  1
Index  0  1
ADR    2  3
EF     3  2
INF    2  3
SS     2  3
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do the job:

```
def frequency(df,col_name): 
    count=df[col_name].value_counts()
    return count
```

In the above function, you should enter the column name as a string. For example:

```
frequency(df,'ADR')
```

If you want to find the counts of all the columns, then it is better to use df.apply as suggested in @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's answer.

Comment: OP wants to calculate value counts for all columns. You'll need to extend your solution.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ From the wording of the problem I thought that the OP is interested in only one column. Anyway, I updated the answer.