# Calculating frequency of DataFrameGroupBy object columns (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

For the following data set:

```
Index    ADR   EF   INF   SS    class   type
1         1     1    0     0     SRI     F
2         1     0    1     1     SRI     h
3         0     1    0     0     NRI     N
4         0     0    1     1     NRI     u
5         1     0    1     1     NRI     l
```

I need to first group data based on values in the column "class" (two groups:SRI, NRI), and then calculate frequency for columns ADR, EF, INF, SS. This is my code:

```
 print (df.groupby("class").ADR.value_counts())
    print (df.groupby("class").EF.value_counts())
    print (df.groupby("class").INF.value_counts())
    print (df.groupby("class").SS.value_counts())
```

But I prefer to write it as a function. Any suggestion ?

Comment: So what is category here?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: what do you mean by "write it as a function"? Should the function print stuff, return data, something else..? Or are you asking how to write functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit more challenging, because you want to perform this action on a variable number of columns.

You can first use `df.groupby` followed by `df.agg`:

```
In [1085]: df.groupby('class').agg(lambda x: [np.bincount(x)]).applymap(lambda x: x[0])
Out[1085]: 
          ADR      EF     INF      SS
class                                
NRI    [2, 1]  [2, 1]  [1, 2]  [1, 2]
SRI    [0, 2]  [1, 1]  [1, 1]  [1, 1]
```

Again, for selective aggregation, a function that accepts a list of columns will do:

```
def foo(df, type, columns):
    return df.groupby(type)[columns].agg(lambda x: [np.bincount(x)]).applymap(lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED, thank you. So there is no way to also pass the value of groupby ("class" here) as an input variable for the function ?

Comment: @Mary Edited. You can, though not sure how it'd work for other columns. Edited my answer.

Comment: @COLDSPEED, would you please explain how "np.bincount(x)" works ?

Comment: @Mary [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) counts the frequency of 0 and 1 :)  Example: `np.bincount([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])` yields `array([6, 3])`

Comment: @COLDSPEE, Sorry. It is has the following error: "Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'", So I need to set type as "int". Yes ?

Comment: @Mary Yes, you must.

Comment: @COLDSPEE. I am sorry, it does not work. I also tried this:                            "def frequencyGroupby2(df, columns):
    df.groupby('class').agg(lambda x: [np.bincount(x)]).applymap(lambda x: x[0])" , but it returns this error: KeyError: 'class'

Comment: @Mary Are you working on different data? class is a column in the data you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this one ...

```
List=[]
List2=[]
for names,df1 in df.groupby('class'):
    print(df1)
    List.append(df1.drop(['class','type'],axis=1).apply(pd.value_counts, axis=0))
    List2.append(names)

pd.concat(List,keys=List2).fillna(0)

Out[110]: 
       ADR  EF  INF  SS
NRI 0  2.0   2    1   1
    1  1.0   1    2   2
SRI 0  0.0   1    1   1
    1  2.0   1    1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [135]: df.drop(['Index','type'],1) \
     ...:   .groupby("class") \
     ...:   .agg([lambda x: x.eq(0).sum(), 'sum']) \
     ...:   .rename(columns={'<lambda>':0,'sum':1}) \
     ...:   .rename_axis(None) \
     ...:   .stack()
Out[135]:
       ADR  EF  INF  SS
NRI 0    2   2    1   1
    1    1   1    2   2
SRI 0    0   1    1   1
    1    2   1    1   1
```

or as a multi-column DF:

```
In [125]: df.drop(['Index','type'],1) \
     ...:   .groupby("class") \
     ...:   .agg([lambda x: x.eq(0).sum(), 'sum']) \
     ...:   .rename(columns={'<lambda>':0,'sum':1}) \
     ...:   .rename_axis(None)
Out[125]:
    ADR    EF    INF    SS
      0  1  0  1   0  1  0  1
NRI   2  1  2  1   1  2  1  2
SRI   0  2  1  1   1  1  1  1
```